# Lazy-high-charts error in a rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

Disclaimer: I'm a complete nooblet trying to teach myself rails =)

My web app produces the below error when I attempt to access the page that is supposed to display charts through the lazy high chart gem:

```
undefined method `html_options' for nil:NilClass
```

and highlights the below HighChart code

```
def high_chart(placeholder, object, &block)
  object.html_options.merge!({:id => placeholder})
  object.options[:chart][:renderTo] = placeholder
  high_graph(placeholder, object, &block).concat(content_tag("div", "", object.html_options))
end
```

Related Files:

**Controller (application_controller.rb)**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

  def graph_orders
    @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.title(:text => "Population vs GDP For 5 Big Countries [2009]")
      f.xAxis(:categories => ["United States", "Japan", "China", "Germany", "France"])
      f.series(:name => "GDP in Billions", :yAxis => 0, :data => [14119, 5068, 4985, 3339, 2656])
      f.series(:name => "Population in Millions", :yAxis => 1, :data => [310, 127, 1340, 81, 65])

      f.yAxis [
        {:title => {:text => "GDP in Billions", :margin => 70} },
        {:title => {:text => "Population in Millions"}, :opposite => true},
      ]

      f.legend(:align => 'right', :verticalAlign => 'top', :y => 75, :x => -50, :layout => 'vertical',)
      f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"column"})
    end
  end
.
.
.      
end
```

**View (dashboard.html.erb)**

```
<% provide(:title, "Dashboard") %>
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<div>
<%= high_chart("orders_chart", @chart) %>
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
.
.
.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require highcharts/highstock
//= require highcharts/highcharts                                                        
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

Gemfile contains jquery-rails 4.0.3 and lazy_high_charts 1.5.4

I also ran an install to add all the highcharts.js, mootools-adapter.js, exporting.js etc... files into my vendor/assets/javascripts/highcharts folder. I also ran `bundle install` afterwards.

I'm guessing there is some kind of inheritance issue for my `@chart` since there is `nil:NilClass` error, but I couldn't find anything online for this issue and have tried different highchart examples and gotten the same error.

Let me know if I need to add any more information/clarification and thanks in advance.

Comment: The controller action that handles the request isn't assigning the `@chart` instance variable.

Comment: Okay I got it to work by removing def graph method from the controller and defining chart in the views as a regular variable instead of an instance variable. However, this isn't an ideal way of separating style from content. I guess I was just confused on assigning in the controller because I thought variables were shared between views and controllers and I don't really know what else to do in the controller because I just need a chart variable to pass to the High Chart function.

Comment: If your template is dashboard.html.erb, you should have a corresponding `dashboard` action (method) in your controller; that's the place you need to be assigning `@chart`. If you are rendering the dashboard template from a different action, then assign `@chart` there.